# NHibernate select query from date field based on Minute

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have a table with a datetime field CreatedOn. I would like to fetch all records where the minute of the datetime field (CreatedOn) is between 31 and 59. I would like to get the NHibernate equivalent of

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.CL_M_Organization
WHERE DATEPART(mi,CreatedOn) BETWEEN 31 AND 59
```

The basic NHibernate query is

```
var result = NHSession.QueryOver<Organization>()
.Where(x=>x.CreatedOn < currentdatetime)
.List<Organization>()
.ToList();
```

The field CreatedOn is of type datetime.

Anyone please help...

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems like you're trying to solve something that could be done differently. You would likely have to execute a raw SQL query and transform the results to objects using NHibernate.

Comment: But is CreatedOn a DateTime property? If so, shouldn't it be CreatedOn.Minute?

Comment: `Minute` is a property of `DateTime` and I doubt NHibernate would be able to perform that reflection properly. It would likely have to pull the results from the database before being able to query against the property.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using an older version of NHibernate, you can use the `MinutePart` extension method (found in the `NHibernate.Criterion` namespace), along with the `IsBetween` extension method:

```
var result = NHSession.QueryOver<Organization>()
    .Where(x => x.CreatedOn.MinutePart().IsBetween(31).And(59))
    .List<Organization>()
    .ToList();
```

However, if you're using a newer version of NHibernate (>= 4), you should just use the `DateTime.Minute` property directly. NHibernate will understand what you're trying to do and translate it into SQL properly:

```
var result = NHSession.QueryOver<Organization>()
    .Where(x => x.CreatedOn.Minute.IsBetween(31).And(59))
    .List<Organization>()
    .ToList();
```

Both of these will generate the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    /* All OrganizationUnit columns */
FROM
    Temp this_ 
WHERE
    datepart(minute, this_.CreatedOn) between 31 and 59;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer on this. I am pleasantly surprised that NHibernate has support for this.